# Unwanted margins on custom paper size Jasper Reports print jobs?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm having some problems with custom page size reports. It seems that the
printing routine is always adding a default margin to the print job, but in the
JRXML i have defined a zero margin for the report.

This problem affects specially reports printed on the printers, as the
report is suppose to be at the exact size of the component.
Because of the inappropriate margin, leaves some component like frame partly unprinted.

Just for clarification, i use the class JRPrintServiceExporter(JasperPrint)
to send the job to the printer. And generating the report in IReport, in preview,the report is shown correctly, but the problem persists on print.

I’m sending together the report’s JRXML for yours consideration.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="officina1" pageWidth="357" pageHeight="595" columnWidth="278" leftMargin="49" rightMargin="30" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="39" uuid="0ac9c201-40e2-4898-a527-ffe7b9b210ef">
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="de.benco.reports.medication.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="REPORT_HAS_EDGE" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(false)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_firstname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_lastname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_inami" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_zipid" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_zipname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_telno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_faxno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TCDOC_doc_mobileno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PI_legalname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PI_firstname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="prescriptions" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="barcode" class="java.awt.Image"/>
    <background>
        <band height="556" splitType="Prevent">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement key="rectangle-5" x="0" y="0" width="297" height="556" uuid="e47f81de-fd8b-47ab-aab7-f3caf2f6ccd4">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_HAS_EDGE}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-3" x="147" y="114" width="1" height="61" uuid="4d2e69cd-158a-49f9-9ea9-10b23244f95b"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-4" x="0" y="175" width="297" height="1" uuid="52c3c6ad-1599-4115-8933-02bb827c3258"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-1" x="150" y="451" width="1" height="93" uuid="270ae48a-6ac8-4f67-a976-b0cb857e87c6"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-2" x="150" y="499" width="147" height="1" uuid="4d0a1214-ba95-4480-9867-2784eccee6e2"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-7" x="90" y="215" width="1" height="236" uuid="578bfbee-ab3d-47b8-8103-fad607bf0d49"/>
            </line>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-8" x="7" y="220" width="78" height="20" uuid="6c78226d-8e09-4c22-9c70-ef68c28d1e5e"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Verdana" size="6" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{medic.benco.voorbehouden}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-15" x="0" y="543" width="293" height="13" uuid="fbf19ae3-575a-4b1c-b098-20c4310e3731"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{medic.benco.title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-16" x="150" y="455" width="147" height="14" uuid="702e52d9-2b8e-4eb4-8fe1-bdc38490c0d0"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{medic.benco.datum}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-17" x="150" y="503" width="147" height="24" uuid="423a8b90-bed2-48af-b766-63041098ffb1"/>
                <box leftPadding="4" rightPadding="4">
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{action.decina.uitvoerbaar}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-18" x="1" y="455" width="149" height="14" uuid="af2434af-b16a-4edf-ad40-de34d8452bb8"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{action.decina.stempel}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-19" x="7" y="180" width="176" height="10" uuid="95a7d607-47b8-42f7-8f35-5430a60c10b2"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{action.decina.invullen}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-20" x="7" y="191" width="82" height="20" uuid="0481174b-2efa-4c07-acee-7b6287539bd7"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{action.decina.rechthebbende}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-21" x="153" y="120" width="136" height="14" uuid="71d41d3a-6732-4bee-8960-33370f64c873"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{action.decina.phd}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-10" x="156" y="538" width="136" height="1" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="6ef16794-0259-4018-a2bc-89d75a9a68b5"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-11" mode="Opaque" x="77" y="206" width="215" height="1" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="3d8b76dc-5ee8-4c36-ac52-57aa30a8a55d"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dotted"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-4" x="0" y="113" width="297" height="1" uuid="a061e20a-a532-4f37-b549-9be8ef35c634"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-4" x="0" y="215" width="297" height="1" uuid="592dad44-6bdb-4249-8c56-14b8d10e960c"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-4" x="0" y="450" width="297" height="1" uuid="02d04e02-acec-4a6e-9d42-aefef82d0eb5"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement key="line-4" x="0" y="543" width="297" height="1" uuid="5e8c73d3-41c4-43df-93f4-1ddc1b0a1e73"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="216" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="155" y="148" width="138" height="25" uuid="726b701b-9864-4889-84f8-72cb66992857"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($F{TCDOC_doc_lastname}==null&&$F{TCDOC_doc_firstname}==null)||("".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_lastname})&&"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_firstname})))
                                    ?"// // // //":$F{TCDOC_doc_lastname}+" "+$F{TCDOC_doc_firstname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-1" x="84" y="197" width="207" height="12" uuid="8ca902d4-db1b-4d2a-be01-da733ef31295"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PI_legalname}+" "+$F{PI_firstname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
                <reportElement key="barcode-1" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="18" y="121" width="112" height="38" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a28724e8-df42-457a-b868-2ef2dd67e64e">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(!"".equalsIgnoreCase($F{TCDOC_doc_inami}.trim()))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement fill="Solid"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{barcode}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-5" positionType="Float" x="4" y="159" width="138" height="13" uuid="53e32567-874f-4d44-a1c2-77efd631a5ab">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{TCDOC_doc_inami}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc_inami}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-1" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="88" y="2" width="205" height="12" uuid="96d39cd8-aee9-411c-b63d-f3311eada6c4"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{prescriptions}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/de/benco/reports/action/templates/decina_sub.jasper")]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="159" height="56" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9fc9ed68-9778-49f8-85e6-ac51940d0023"/>
            </frame>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-3" x="0" y="21" width="150" height="14" uuid="824ad70c-e30a-482a-87b0-c4b2eace4d50"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc}==null||"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc})?"// // // //":($F{TCDOC_doc}+" "+((($F{TCDOC_doc_lastname}==null&&$F{TCDOC_doc_firstname}==null)||("".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_lastname})&&"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_firstname})))
                                    ?"...........":$F{TCDOC_doc_lastname}+" "+$F{TCDOC_doc_firstname}))]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-10" x="1" y="30" width="149" height="14" uuid="31a4c336-4c64-474e-ba2c-3ee9d88af772"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc_address}==null||"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_address})?"// // // //":$F{TCDOC_doc_address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="staticText-10" x="1" y="42" width="149" height="14" uuid="fe1fb078-234a-448c-97a4-71ee4a16c93c"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($F{TCDOC_doc_zipid}==null&&$F{TCDOC_doc_zipid}==null)||("".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_zipname})&&"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_zipname})))
                                    ?"// // // //":$F{TCDOC_doc_zipid}+" "+$F{TCDOC_doc_zipname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="staticText-10" x="1" y="54" width="149" height="12" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="120bf709-0584-4454-a72a-63156181bb09">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc_telno} !=null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc_telno}==null||"".equals($F{TCDOC_doc_telno})?"// // // //":$F{TCDOC_doc_telno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-4" positionType="Float" x="0" y="64" width="150" height="13" uuid="f4a57159-e72a-47c9-9baa-dcdb71b55d9a">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{TCDOC_doc_inami}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Serif" size="8" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TCDOC_doc_inami}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-12" x="221" y="5" width="0" height="0" uuid="42d0d35c-4787-4b1e-ba22-d7697ad12bf4"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-6" x="161" y="30" width="131" height="13" uuid="ac27a1f8-fdb7-4e81-b88d-d188a905d34a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```